# Getting mutliple lists from list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list like this :

```
[{'have a nice day': '{"have a nice day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'good day': '{"good day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'have a cheerful day': '{"have a cheerful day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'good morning': '{"good morning": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'gm,Good Morning': '{"gm,Good Morning": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'gd mng': '{"gd mng": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}'']
```

I want separate lists like this:

```
L1 = [{'have a nice day': '{"have a nice day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}']

L2 = ['good day': '{"good day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}']

L3 = ['good morning': '{"good morning": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}']

L4 = ......
```

Comment: But why? There's no reason to use few variables instead of list.

Comment: Does not really make sense.... your `Lx` variable are just the member of the previous list: you can access those with `[]` operator from the original list.

Comment: Your list is not a valid Python structure. You're mixing brackets and quotes all over the place and the structure is not clear. Is this a list-of-dicts-of-strings, or a list-of-strings-of-dicts?

Comment: Thank you for the responses, this is a List -of - dicts-of- strings.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia sir , i want to train a model with each list separately , That's the reason I wanted them in separate lists. Thank you.

Comment: The question is really unclear.... but this could work: `L1 = [L[0]]`

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need:

```
arr = [{'have a nice day': '{"have a nice day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'good day': '{"good day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'have a cheerful day': '{"have a cheerful day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'good morning': '{"good morning": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'gm,Good Morning': '{"gm,Good Morning": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}', 'gd mng': '{"gd mng": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}'}]

separate = [{k: v} for k, v in arr[0].items()]
```

If you print this out the output will be:

```
{'have a nice day': '{"have a nice day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}'}
{'good day': '{"good day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}'}
{'have a cheerful day': '{"have a cheerful day": "(\'Good Day\',\'PartOfDay\')"}'}
{'good morning': '{"good morning": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}'}
{'gm,Good Morning': '{"gm,Good Morning": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}'}
{'gd mng': '{"gd mng": "(\'Good Morning\',\'PartOfDay\')"}'}
```